# Site trap_exit down

Tags: erlang

I am new to Erlang and besides reading books and manuals, I like to look at existing code. The site trapexit.org looked nice, but it is currently down. 
Is there somebody out there that could restart the thing, or even better, is there a well maintained, up to date code repository somewhere else?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Erlang Central](https://erlangcentral.org/) has most of the content from Trapexit - check the Documentation tab.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. How could I have missed this one?

Comment: It is relatively new. I'm not sure who maintains trapexit, but a redirect to Erlang Central would have been a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd look around at Bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/repo/all/relevance?name=erlang&language=erlang or Github: https://github.com/search?l=Erlang&q=erlang&ref=cmdform&type=Repositories

But no, I do not know of any other Erlang-focused site similar to Trapexit